# Ionic AngularJS: Attach image and Text to the header of Ionic View Not Displaying

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have made a code to attach image and a text along side to the header bar of ionic view. This is the code snippet:

```
<ion-view align-title="left">
<h1 style="margin-left:100px" class="title">
<img class="title-image" src="http://www.ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-white.svg" width="123" height="43" />
</h1>
<h1 class="title">Titled Text</h1>
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label style="border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px;" class="item item-input">
                <input focus-on="focusMe" type="text" ng-model="register.username" placeholder="Choose username">
            </label>
            <label style="margin-top: 10px; border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px;" class="item item-input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Choose password" ng-model="register.password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <a style="margin-top: 100px; border: 3px solid red; border-radius:5px; background-color: #ff6000 class="button button-block button-positive">Next</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is the plunk that I have made.

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZctWjCx48m4QT6FKgOCw?p=preview)

Please how can I make image and text appear to the header bar of ionic view?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your Plunker is entirely broken...

Comment: That is what makes it a challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a small demo for you,

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7LCTj3?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<ion-view title="Home" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
         <h4>myApp</h4>
        <div style="width:100%">
            <img style="height: 16px;
        margin-top: 9px;" src="https://placehold.it/85x25" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome user</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my Problem/challenge.
Since I found it difficult doing something like this

```
<ion-view  align-title="left">
<h1 style="margin-left:100px" class="title">
<img class="title-image" src="http://www.ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-white.svg" width="123" height="43" />
</h1>
<h1 class="title">Titled Text</h1>
```

To add image and text to the bar, then I ended up doing this:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <img class="title-image" src=".../ionic-logo-white.svg" width="30" height="43" /></h1>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Don't know what you might think about it but it worked. As it placed an image at the header and I also have a text at the header bar as well. Just a simple logic